# Memory leaks while web scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

I'm trying to index all movies, series... Of this web page: [www.newpct1.com](http://newpct1.com/). For each media content I want to save its title, torrent file URL and the size of the file. To do this I'm using NodeJS with the modules cheerio (extract HTML content with JQuery like sintax) and request (make requests). The code is as follows:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');


console.log('\"Site\",\"Title\",\"Size\",\"URL\"');
const baseURL = 'http://newpct1.com/';
const sites = ['documentales/pg/', 'peliculas/pg/', 'series/pg/', 'varios/pg/'];
for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
  let site = sites[i].split('/')[0];
  for (let j = 1; true; j++) { // Infinite loop
    let siteURL = baseURL + sites[i] + j;
    // getMediaURLs
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    request(siteURL, (err, resp, body) => {
      if (!err) {
        let $ = cheerio.load(body);
        let lis = $('li', 'ul.pelilist');
        // If exists media
        if (lis.length) {
          $('a', lis).each((k, elem) => {
            let mediaURL = $(elem).attr('href');
            // getMediaAttrs
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            request(mediaURL, (err, resp, body) => {
              if (!err) {
                let $ = cheerio.load(body);
                let title = $('strong', 'h1').text();
                let size = $('.imp').eq(1).text().split(':')[1];
                let torrent = $('a.btn-torrent').attr('href');
                console.log('\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"', site, title, size,
                  torrent);
              }
            });
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
          });
        }
      }
    });
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }
}
```

The issue of this code is that never ends the execution, throws this error (memory leak):

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

   22242 ms: Mark-sweep 1372.4 (1439.0) -> 1370.7 (1439.0) MB, 1088.7 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
   23345 ms: Mark-sweep 1370.7 (1439.0) -> 1370.7 (1439.0) MB, 1103.0 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
   24447 ms: Mark-sweep 1370.7 (1439.0) -> 1370.6 (1418.0) MB, 1102.1 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
   25527 ms: Mark-sweep 1370.6 (1418.0) -> 1370.6 (1418.0) MB, 1079.5 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x272c0e23fa99 <JS Object>
    1: httpify [/home/marco/node_modules/caseless/index.js:~50] [pc=0x3f51b4a2c2c5] (this=0x1e65c39fbdb9 <JS Function module.exports (SharedFunctionInfo 0x1e65c39fb581)>,resp=0x2906174cf6a9 <a Request with map 0x2efe262dbef9>,headers=0x11e0242443f1 <an Object with map 0x2efe26206829>)
    2: init [/home/marco/node_modules/request/request.js:~144] [pc=0x3f51b4a3ee1d] (this=0x2906174cf6a9 <a Requ...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x10d3f9c [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction> v8::internal::Factory::New<v8::internal::JSFunction>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [node]
 6: v8::internal::Factory::NewFunction(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Context>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 7: v8::internal::Factory::NewFunctionFromSharedFunctionInfo(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Context>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 8: v8::internal::Runtime_NewClosure_Tenured(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
 9: 0x3f51b47060c7
```

I try to execute in a machine with more RAM (16 GB) but throws the same error.

I also made an heap snapshot, but I don't see where is the problem. The snapshot is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Ysugq64wdLSHdHVHctUXZaNGM

Comment: I believe you are doing unlimited requests there, and requests take space

Comment: It looks like. If I do a break of two loops after the first iteration works weel. I don't know how to limit this requests or do some of this, wait until be completed, and continue with the rest.

Comment: In my mind the `console.log(...)`s have to be executing all the time, but It doesn't happend that. I belive that when all the requests have been made, it starts printing to the CL.

Comment: On another note, with that infinite loop you are only retrieving from 'documentales/pg/'...

Comment: The infinite loop is to retrive all the pages of one site (until the are no more pages), and the first `for` loop is to iterate over the sites.

Comment: There is no break present in the code, so that "until there are no more pages" is not happening

Comment: @juvian OH F***!

Comment: Is the website provider actually OK with you scraping their content?

Comment: `Infinite loop` by design will create memory leaks if you do not end them properly. That's where you should start investigating.

Comment: @k0pernikus their content is freely accessible (it's in the usage policies and legal advice). Also I'm going to controll the requests per minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General idea of how to get rid of that infinite loop: you start making requests for each site, and whenever one completes, you request the following page for that site.

```
for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
  let site = sites[i].split('/')[0];
  let siteURL = baseURL + sites[i];
  scrapSite(siteURL, 0);
}

function scrapSite(siteURL, idx) {
    request(siteURL + idx, (err, resp, body) => {
        if (!err) {
            ...
            scrapMedia();

            if (pageExists) {
                scrapSite(siteURL, idx + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks (the only thing that leaks is my mind haha). BTW Elegant solution (recursion).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to start node with `--expose-gc` flag, force GC by calling `$ = null; global.gc();` before/after `console.log` call. And try to test that variant.

If problem be the same we try to perform algo changes and optimize memory usage.

Very useful refs:
https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/830
https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/263

Comment: The error still happening, but looks like the memory increasing is lower. I'm going to read the references.

Comment: @MarcoCanora ok, tell about you investigation and we try to solve problem. One of way is avoid nested requests and perform it separately. At first stage extract sites mediaURLs, clean memory and then work with mediaURLs.